# Hough Circle returning weird results OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use a HoughCircle from openCV with below code

```
Mat _image, gray;
_image = imread("c:\\Bin.jpg", 1);
cvtColor(_image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
std::vector<Vec3f> Circles;
HoughCircles(gray, Circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 500, 100, 100, 6, 100);
```

The result is weird though my vector comes back with a size of 1537228672805996190 and the points contain some negative values.

Im building in visual studio 2013 and I was playing around with other stuff and it works fine i.e. the canny edge worked fine. I tried changing the values around increasing the minumum distance and min and max rad but I always get a huge result.  I tested displaying the image going into this after the GaussianBlur and it looks fine.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: You're probably using release libs in debug mode, or viceversa. Or using libs compiled with a compiler other than vc12. Or using x86 libs on a x64 project  or viceversa